# socket.io network connectivity failure detection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am facing problem with ERR connection Timed Out using socket.io whenever user lost access to network. 
The thing is that when user is losing connection with the network the server does not notice it and it seems like user is still able to trigger some events. 
How to properly disconnect both:
-client from the server from client perspective on network failure
-client from the server from server perspective on network failure

So basically I have hosted an app here: askit-break-scheduler.herokuapp.com, if I then connect with app and suspend my connection, for example by putting my laptop into sleep mode, some data is lost and my nickname seems to be set to undefined. Can you please help me to figure out what am I missing here? Code can be found here: github.com/Hoopoe99PL/break-tracker

I manage http connection as follows in node:

```js
    app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/src/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/src"));
```

and then manage the IO connection and disconnect event:

```js
io.on("connection", (socket)=>{


 //some other code here


    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{

// deleting all sessions data, clearing all entries in arrays and Maps regarding that socket

        cancelUserStatus(socket.id);
        users.delete(socket.id);
        io.emit('u-users-list', Array.from(users));
        clearInterval(intervals.get(socket.id));
        intervals.delete(socket.id);
    });

});
```

my problem is that whenever user suspends network connection and then tries to reconnect again it seems like some data is missing because for example the username is set to undefined.

I have view server's logs and there seems not to be any output about new connection as I print new connection's socket id into the console earlier in the code as well.

I am thinking about somehow forcing user to reconnect again to the server because it all seems like when user lost network connection and then gets it again he is instantly connected to the app but the verification process being launched at the start of the app when entering url into web browser seems not to be triggered here.

Any client side handlers would be needed I guess.

EDIT: The client side handlers provided in comments below might be an answer, will test later on.

Comment: just to confirm, given that you say you've been searching a lot: did you check the docs and issue list on https://github.com/socketio/socket.io?

Comment: So, socket.io uses heartbeats to attempt to detect when the connection has dropped and when that happens, it closes the socket and attempts a reconnect.  If that reconnect succeeds, it picks up where it left off and no messages should be lost (they are cached internally when the connection is having problems).  This should all be transparent if the connection can be restored.  socket.io has configuration parameters that determine how long and how often it tries to reconnect and, if it fails to make a connection in that time, it will give up and announce an error.

Comment: So, given all that, it's unclear exactly what behavior you're observing and what you want to do about it?  The first thing is to make sure you're listening to all the possible errors on the client-side socket so you can know about things like reconnect failures.

Comment: So basically I have hosted an app here: http://askit-break-scheduler.herokuapp.com/, if I then connect with app and suspend my connection, for example by putting my laptop into sleep mode, some data is lost and my nickname seems to be set to undefined. Can you please help me to figure out what am I missing here? Code can be found here: https://github.com/Hoopoe99PL/break-tracker

Comment: Please edit your question to include those specific details and then add to your question the relevant socket.io connection and error handling code.  If the problem is that nickname on the server is set to `undefined`, then post the relevant server code too.  To attract help here, you need to "set the table" to entice people to help you by describing the problem as specifically as possible and then showing (in your question), the relevant code.  That's how you attract quick and accurate answers here.

Comment: You can probably learn more about the client status if you add client-side event handlers on the socket for `connect_error`, `connect_timeout`, `reconnect`, `reconnecting`, `reconnect_error` and `reconnect_failed`.  On at least some of these events, you probably want to show feedback in the UI that you are not currently connected.

Comment: Thank you jfriend00, I edited the question hoping it can be now more understandable. Sorry for that. As I find some free time now I will try to implement some handlers on those events and let know here in comments how does it work. Thanks for the attention and help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have clients that have connection issues, then socket.io will already be trying to detect those connection issues and reconnect.  About the best you can do on top of that is to show feedback in the UI that there are connection issues and, once you lose the connection perhaps you even disable the controls or put up an error when they click on a control to inform that user that you've lost your connection and can't carry out the operation.

The relevant client-side events that you can listen to are:

```
error
connect_error
connect_timeout
reconnect
reconnecting
reconnect_error
reconnect_failed
```

You can read in the [client-side doc](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99) what exactly each of these events mean.  Some of these events mean you've lost the connection and some of these events are steps along the way to trying to re-establish a connection.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Implemented this solution as well as gathered some more information from here https://socket.io/docs/client-api/ and everything is now working as expected! Thank you for your help. Appreciate it.